# Combining Multiple Web Site

Tags: apache, web-applications

I intended to combine multiple web site (A, B, C) into one. My plan is write a web server (master) in Apache that route to the rest of web sites. instead of just redirect, I think it will be better if I can inject html navigation bar code to every deliver web pages like

http://webproxy.stealthy.co/index.php?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl

does.

Does Apache can do such an injection?
Are there better or alternative ways to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: can you tell me which part?